# Access a variable from different classes that are in different namespaces

Tags: c#, mvvm, internals

I have a MVVM application, and I need to declare a variable somewhere and access it from everywhere in my assembly, that is, from different classes in different namespaces. I have tried to declare an internal variable in the main class but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a `public class` with `public` variables

Comment: `internal` means visible in this Assembly. What you need is a `public` variable which is globally visible. Also, if you need the same variable (same value and all) everywhere you should make it `public static`

Comment: You want a Service which will be able to be Injected where needed.

Comment: How did you declare the variable? How did you try to access it?

Comment: @MindSwipe No, `internal` means accessible in this assembly and friends. It has nothing to do with namespaces.

Comment: Whta you tried so far? Please provide some code

Comment: @KlausGütter fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a simple "Service"

```
namespace en.my.services
{
     public class VariableService
     {
         public string SomeVariable {get; set;}
     }
}
```

Which you can inject where needed:

```
using en.my.services; // Make Service namespace known

namespace en.my.clients 
{
    public class MyServiceClient
    {
        VariableService svc = null;

        public MyServiceClient ( VariableService varsserv ) // <- Parameter-Injection via 
                                                            // your DI Framework
        {   
            svc = varserv;
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            svc.SomeVariable = "Update";
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend to also use an interface. So you can easily (unit-)test by mocking the interface. So, you'd have `IVariableService` and `VariableService` implementing it. The clients would take the interface and your DI Framework config would make the connection from the interface to a singleton instance of the implementation.

Comment: Yes I have done it using interfaces and DI, but once you instantiate class MyServiceClient (MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(new VariableService())) where VariableService is a class which has a constructor and implements an interface, then I need to have access to client variable everywhere from different classes placed in different namespaces. how to do this?

Comment: You can inject the Service class whereever you need it. Just tell your DI framework, it shall make it a singleton. Only mind, it won't be thread safe out of the box.

Comment: I only need to inject it once, then use always the same variable 'Client' everywhere.

Comment: Then you have exactly the problem you have. Inject where needed. That's the idea behind that pattern.

Comment: Yes, I know but I only inject it once because I do not need to inject it more times. It's a type of "Inicialisation". Then I would like to use the variable client everywhere because once injected nothing changes. Then through this variable I have access to a method that I use frequently everywhere.

Comment: I am aware of that. But as you obviously figured out: that won't work.

Comment: ok, finally I have done what you suggested. I think it's the only way to do it. thx.